# A more formal way of saying "to manage to do something"

Tags: single-word-requests

I always think there must be a fresher, more elegant way of saying ***to manage to do something***. I find myself simply avoiding the expression when I come across it, and now I would need again a solution. When I look for synonyms of this expression, dictionaries like [powerthesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/manage_to_do/synonyms) do not provide many interesting choices.

There is always the other option of ***to succeed in doing something*** but I find it has too many words and rather encumbers the sentence.

I am looking for other ways of saying this in general, but I will still give an example:

> If we (manage) not to lose hope, we will be able to give hope to others.

What verb could replace *manage* here?

Note: I need a verb which can be followed by ***to do something***.

Comment: This is only an example, probably a poor one, of situation in which I need to express the idea of succeeding in doing something.

Comment: If you need a verb to **complete** a phrase, the tag should be SWR not 'phrase-requests'. And you should supply a complete sentence. Research should also be shown (and remember that synonyms can often be found that work in constructions not accepting the original). // The only other verb I've found (_contrive_ not being really suitable)  that fits in ' ___ to do something' is _effect_, which is rare, appearing mainly in a few set expressions, and nowhere near as good a choice as _manage_.

Comment: If we handle this situation properly.....  if we can work through this situation..... if we come through this unscathed....,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can contrive to answer your question by writing this sentence.

> contrive = to arrange a situation or event, or arrange for something to happen, using clever planning
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contrive)

The usage "contrive to" was more popular in the past according to google ngram but still lives on and seems appropriate to your context.

One example might be: “*If we can somehow contrive not to lose hope, we will be able to inspire others.*”

Here is an example (sorry, only available as an image rather than text) taken from

[How to Succeed](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22contrive%20to%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1932,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl)

[image]

Comment: @fev yes I was. Sorry for delay. I hate doing answers on an iPad, where manipulation of symbols is so difficult, and moved to laptop.

Comment: So can I say "If we contrive not to lose hope"? Could you insert a n example of sentence with "contrive", if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: I have quickly added an example. Others may do better.

Comment: @Anton: it does match the meaning I am looking for, but I am not sure it's common enough.

Comment: _Contrive_ is marginal here. As others have said, it sounds unnatural here (KannE puts this better), but also about half the usually cited dictionaries have the 'scheming / clever planning' sense/subsense as the default rather than the 'bring about'.

Answer (score 0):

While not *exactly* what you’re asking for, in your example you could replace the entire bit with “keep”.

> If we can **keep** hope, we will be able to give hope to others.

This would work similarly for words like faith or belief.